# Upload of files fails in IE 9 / 10

Tags: php, internet-explorer, file-upload, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I have the following problem:

On a website I'm coding for a client I have a form where you can upload images (up to 5, seperate file-input elements (so no problem caused by a flash / javascript solution)).
But sometimes the upload fails directly (nearly instantly the "Page cannot be displayed"-page is shown) or the request does not contain the files.

This is not an issue of file-size (as it happens sometimes, no matter if the files are larger (~2-3MB) or really small (150kB)) or request timeout (as the upload fails directly and not always - but too often ;-)).

Another weird thing: I tried to analyze the whole thing using Fiddler. But while using Fiddler the problem simply does not occur.

Any ideas?

Tested in IE9/10 on Win7/8
Chrome, FF etc. work fine, of course ;-)

/edit: I use a really simple test script (fails like the regular webapp)

```
<?='<!DOCTYPE html>'?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://www.site.com/upl-test/index.php" method="post"     enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="img_file0" />
        <input type="file" name="img_file1" />
        <input type="file" name="img_file2" />
        <input type="file" name="img_file3" />
        <input type="file" name="img_file4" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    <?php 
    if(!empty($_FILES)){
        echo '<hr /><pre>';
        var_dump($_FILES);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not enough info: need some code here, the html form, the php script that handles the upload...

Comment: Your doctype declaration says `DOTYPE` to start with -- and why do you have it inside php tags?

Comment: The above script works fine for me on Win7/IE9. What's the actual value of the form's `action` attribute? And have you got any add-ons enabled on IE?

Comment: you can test it here http://www.fahrradanzeigen.com/upl-test/index.php

Comment: i testes further and found out that the problem only occurs the first time after i started the ie and with image files. if i try it with files other then image files it does not fail.